# How to reference auto incremented Id with varchar prefix in another table

Tags: mysql

How do you reference an Auto incremented id with a varchar prefix in another table? I want my user to be able to log on with the Id which carries the prefix ED1501 and not their EmpNumber which is 1

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
EmpNumber int identity (1, 1),
Id as 'ED15'+right('00'+cast(EmpNumber as varchar(2)), 2) persisted,
EmpImage varchar(200),
TitleID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Title(TitleID),
EmpTypeID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EmployeeType(EmpTypeID),
PositionID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Position(PositionID)NULL,
EmpName varchar (50),
EmpSurname varchar (50),
EmpDOB date,
EmpID_PassportNumber varchar (13),
EmpEmail varchar(255),
CountryID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Country(CountryID),
ProvinceID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Province(ProvinceID),
City varchar(50),
Suburb varchar (50),
Street varchar (50),
PostalCode varchar (4),
BankID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Bank(BankID),
 AccountNumber varchar (20),
TaxNumber varchar (20),
Salary float,
WorkingHours int,
constraint PK_Employee primary key (EmpNumber)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE LoginDetails
(
EmpNumber int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(EmpNumber),
[Password] varchar(8),
SecurityQuestion varchar(50),
 SecurityAnswer varchar(20)
);
GO
```

Currently I am referencing using the EmpNumber as I get data type errors when I try to reference with the Id which is varchar. I want to know because when i move to designing presentation tier i want the user to type in their Id and password not their EmpNumber.

Comment: That's not mysql syntax. there is no `identity` in mysql, and you cannot define a field as being the result of an expression.

Answer (score 0):

*It is **not possible** to create a [Declarative Referential Integrity (DRI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_Referential_Integrity) relation from `X` <-> `Y + X`* in standard SQL; although there is technically no problem in querying such a relation.

*The primary and foreign columns must share the same value for DRI*. An additional `Z = Y + X` field<sup>1</sup> could be created for a `Z` <-> `Z` DRI association; but it is important to note that the source and targets (after now having introduce a redundant key) match.

*Anyway*, while the above is for the 'title problem' it is probably irrelevant to "I want my user to be able to log on with the Id". To address this, simply update the 'authentication check' query - *with a Join on the EmpNumber*<sup>2</sup> - to use the field as the 'login principal; this task itself does not call for a DRI to be established with the "ED1" ID and there would only be a FK relation setup for the EmpNumber columns.

---

<sup>1</sup> This field must usually be handled at the application-insert layer or an instead-of insert trigger. Even SQL Server, which even supports persisted computed columns, still [does *not* allow computed columns to be used in DRI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx).

<sup>2</sup> For example:

```
select ..
from Employees e
join LoginDetails ld
  on e.EmpNumber = ld.EmpNumber       -- this is the Relationship: X <-> X
where e.Id = @theIdWithED1Prepended
  and ld.password = @thePassword
```

---

Also, using varchar(8) is 'wrong' because

1. it's definitely not a correctly-hashed/salted password - plain text password storage should be avoided; and
2. passwords should be encouraged to be longer pass-phrases anyway - there is no reason for an antiquated 8 character limit.

Answer (score 0):

Ive figured it out all I had to was copy the Id

```
Id as 'ED15'+right('00'+cast(EmpNumber as varchar(2)), 2) persisted,
```

Into the LoginDetails table under the FORIEGN KEY reference

```
EmpNumber int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(EmpNumber),
```

Then use the following select statement in  visual studio now i can log on using ED1501 instead of 1

```
string sql= "select * FROM LoginDetails WHERE Id = '" + txtEmpNumber.Text + "' AND Password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "' ";
```

Thank you all for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: Or you could use a join an not duplicate data, but whatever. In any case, please *fix* the broken code that is prone to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).